# can i install both tensorflow and tensorflow lite?

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, python-3.7, armv7

Can I install both Tensor-Flow and Tensor-Flow lite ? I using Raspberry Pi 4, Python3, cp37, version is armv7l. Tensor-Flow version = 2.1

I have a folder for Tensor-Flow but when I run the program, the speed is very slow, detection sometime incorrect. My Raspberry Pi do not have any GPU, Is it possible to install TensorFlow Lite? Will it corrupted of the software?

Comment: Are you running a keras model on raspberry pi rather that `.tflite` model?

Comment: Hi @Kaveh, yes I'm running on Keras Model which i had followed step by step with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weT_aJ7SJH8

Comment: It's better to convert your model to `.tflite` first, then use it to get much higher performance.

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks Kaveh, but I very new to this software could you teach me step by step?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert) out.